# VMWare Kernel Modules will not compile or update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel, vmware

Kernel Module Update was required when opening `VMWare` client (`vmplayer`) then following error occurs. Any idea would be appreciated.

```
Unable to start services.
See log file /tmp/vmware-root/setup-NNN.log for details    (Note: NNN looks like random numbers)
```

On GUI that show progress of updating, "Virtual Netowork Device" show red flag appears. Content of .log file is here: http://pastebin.com/wEKT5UHf

[This page](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1855981.html) suggests installing `linux-headers-generic` and `build-essential`, which are already installed on mine (thus no good).

This could be 1st execution of `vmplayer` on my machine since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10.

Environment: VMware Player 4.0.3 build-703057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, that VMWare didn't work any after updating to Ubuntu 12.04. Instead of installing a patch from an untrusted page, I just downloaded and installed the latest version VMware-Player-5.0.0 from the VMWare-Page:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0

So far, it seems to work properly. I hope it's OK for you too.

Comment: While @izx' solution worked perfectly (esp. at that moment when I asked this question), I feel this is more ideal and worked just fine on my machine. So I re-chose this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare is behind the times and the VMWare modules will not compile by default on kernel 3.2, which Ubuntu 12.04 uses.

Please use the patch available [in this blog post](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/), and then try to compile again.

I can confirm that the patch worked for me on both VMWare Player 4.x and Workstation 8.x on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It works perfect. As I commented in the same blog, only tweak I needed was to modify `plreqver` with correct `vmplayer` version, in the given .sh file in the patch (http://goo.gl/fF4Yk). Thanks!

Comment: On a follow-up note, It happens with 4.0.4 but same patch was effective.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me also, only changing the plreqver variable to correct version (in my case 4.0.3) as mentioned above.

These are my system versions:

- vmware-player 4.0.3.703057
- Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit
- Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae